# cleaning dataframe columns with single cell arrays of different types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am working on a large dataframe with multiple columns. However, some of columns have data in the form of arrays with in arrays (single value). I need to convert the dataframe columns with only cell values i.e., without the array element style. I have tried flatten, squeeze in different ways, but could not get the output in the way I am looking.
Following code reproduces the data format I am working at present:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[[10]],[[20]],[[30]],[[40]]]
b=[[50],[60],[70],[80]]
c=[90,100,110,120]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b,c)),columns=['a','b','c'])
print(df)
```

The output of the above is:

```
        a     b    c
0  [[10]]  [50]   90
1  [[20]]  [60]  100
2  [[30]]  [70]  110
3  [[40]]  [80]  120
```

However, I am looking to get the output as below:

```
    a   b    c
0  10  50   90
1  20  60  100
2  30  70  110
3  40  80  120
```

It would really help, if you could suggest how to approach this problem.

The head of the actual dataframe is given below:

```
           acoeff         bcoeff  refdiff  ref18
0  [[0.33907555]]  [11.51908656]    0.000  0.001
1  [[0.34024954]]  [11.45693353]    0.001  0.001
2  [[0.34134777]]  [11.40045124]    0.002  0.001
3  [[0.34297324]]  [11.33036004]    0.004  0.001
4  [[0.34373931]]   [11.2991075]    0.005  0.001
```

The head in the dictionary format given below:

```
{'acoeff': {0: '[[0.33907555]]', 1: '[[0.34024954]]', 2: '[[0.34134777]]', 3: '[[0.34297324]]', 4: '[[0.34373931]]'}, 'bcoeff': {0: '[11.51908656]', 1: '[11.45693353]', 2: '[11.40045124]', 3: '[11.33036004]', 4: '[11.2991075]'}, 'refdiff': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.001, 2: 0.002, 3: 0.004, 4: 0.005}, 'ref18': {0: 0.001, 1: 0.001, 2: 0.001, 3: 0.001, 4: 0.001}}
```

Comment: is the nesting level pre-defined or arbitrary? Is is conserved within a column?

Comment: the nesting is not arbitrary and is uniform within a column.

Comment: all the answers given below worked on the example dataframe I have shared, however strangely on my actual dataframe none worked.

Comment: can you provide a sample?

Comment: I have added the head of the actual dataframe in the question now.

Comment: can you provide your sample as dictionary? `df.head().to_dict()`, to ensure there isn't an unexpected type

Comment: As I expected, you have strings ;)

Comment: added the head info in the dictionary format.

Comment: you can use `df.update(df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').apply(lambda c: pd.to_numeric(c.str.strip('[]'))))
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### strings

strip the `[]` and convert to numeric:

```
(df.update(df.select_dtypes(exclude='number')
             .apply(lambda c: pd.to_numeric(c.str.strip('[]'))))
 )
print(df)
```

#### real lists

You can unnest the list with the `str` locator:

```
df['a'].str[0].str[0]
```

output:

```
0    10
1    20
2    30
3    40
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

To automatize things a bit, you can use a recursive function:

```
def unnest(x):
    from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
    if is_numeric_dtype(x):
        return x
    else:
        return unnest(x.str[0])

df2 = df.apply(unnest)
```

variant using the first item of each Series to determine the nesting level:

```
def unnest(x):
    from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
    if len(x)>0 and isinstance(x.iloc[0], list):
        return unnest(x.str[0])
    else:
        return x

df2 = df.apply(unnest)
```

output:

```
    a   b    c
0  10  50   90
1  20  60  100
2  30  70  110
3  40  80  120
```

###### arbitrary nesting

If you had an arbitrary nesting for each cell, you could use the same logic per element:

```
def unnest(x):
    if isinstance(x, list) and len(x)>0:
        return unnest(x[0])
    else:
        return x
    
df2 = df.applymap(unnest)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the great help. the solution worked. strings were not noticed while printing the head, as well as while observing it with df.info().

Comment: you're welcome, too bad this was a simple string problem, the other interpretation was more interesting :p

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution. But it works.

```
def ravel_series(s):
    try:
        return np.concatenate(s).ravel()
    except ValueError:
        return s

df.apply(ravel_series)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

**Code:**

```
def clean(el):
  if any(isinstance(i, list) for i in el):
    return el[0][0]
  elif isinstance(row, list):
    return el[0]

df['a'] = df.a.apply(clean)
df['b'] = df.b.apply(clean)

print(df)
```

---

**Output:**

```
    a   b    c
0  10  50   90
1  20  60  100
2  30  70  110
3  40  80  120
```